# Dropping X number o tables in sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a database with 1000s of tables. I want to drop all of them except say 15 of them.

Is there a quick way to do this?

Comment: You can run this query: `SELECT 'DROP TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ';' FROM sys.tables WHERE type = 'U' AND name NOT IN (/*** your 15 tables here ***/)`, then copy-paste the results and execute them

Comment: @Lamak Shouldn't that be an answer?

Comment: @techturtle maybe, yeah. But don't worry, answers will come anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the below sql statement and get the list of tables you want then copy and paste the results to actually drop the tables.

```
SELECT 'drop table ' + t.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + T.TABLE_NAME + ';' 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables t
WHERE table_name LIKE '%bob%'
```